# Upvote = Permalink

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, usability, share-this

I've noticed, lately, that on upvoting a question the permalink of this question is shown and selected.

[image: Permalink]

Normally, after upvoting a question, I use the arrow key to read the answers. With the focus on the selected permalink, the page doesn't scroll.

As I haven't clicked on the [link] link, this is unexpected behavior and should be avoided.

Comment: +1: I don't know if I've seen the (lack of) scrolling behavior (with Safari on OSX Leopard) but I've most certainly seen the inappropriate link dialog being triggered.

Comment: When seeing this question i nearly automatically clicked on the 'close' link.

Comment: I think this functionality (the pop over) is fine but I don't care for it stealing focus...

Comment: @BenBrocka, Hi Ben, nice to see you here. I agree with you.

Comment: Think it's worth a separate feature request? It's clear the box is intended, the focus stealing seems more...bleh

Comment: @BenBrocka, funny you should mention, but I did... [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102331/upvote-permalink-improvement-suggestion) was first heavily downvoted, but has 3 votes at this moment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is by design -- certain recent "hot" questions will prompt you to share them upon upvoting.

This happens at random a certain percentage of the time.

Comment: OK, that's cool. It just happened to me twice.

Comment: Not sure about anyone else, but I find these prompts incredibly annoying.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @CamJackson and posted another meta question similar to this one, they are confusing and should be able to be dismissed easier.  I dont think I will ever ever have reason to facebook or twitter a question `randomly`!

Comment: I third this. Perhaps a short(!) timer could be put on the share box...