# Upvoting a question opens the 'share a link to this question' dialog?

Tags: support, up-votes, share-this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upvote = Permalink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101383/upvote-permalink)

I just noticed that the **share a link to this question** dialog pops up automatically when you upvote a question on Stack Overflow (but not on *Meta* Stack Overflow, interestingly enough). How new is this feature? I haven't seen it documented in the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/162705) yet.

Comment: @TimStone Indeed it is. Thanks for pointing that out!