# Permalink pops up sometimes when using MultiCollider SuperDropdown

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I don't know if this is just a general browser thing (I use Chrome) but occasionally when I click on a link from the MultiCollider SuperDropdown, the opened page has the permalink box already opened:

[image]

Has anyone else noticed this?  Possible bug where the mouse down from the SuperDropdown is passing through to the new page?  I've only seen it happen with link, not the edit-close-flag options next to it.

Comment: Related: [upvote == permalink](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101383/upvote-permalink).

Comment: If I remember right, this is `[status-bydesign]`, some odd heuristic or something.

Comment: @Mat I didn't know it was called permalink.  Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, "permalink" is a generic term not limited to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design -- on current hot questions we show the share link on load to invite sharing, a certain random percentage of the time.

Comment: OK, good to know.