# SO emails being caught in Gmail spam?

Tags: discussion, support, email

So apparently some (or all?) automated emails by SO are being filtered as spam by Google.

Has the team been looking into this issue?

[image]

Comment: Mark it "not spam" for a start, maybe that'll help a bit.

Comment: Well, those bounty ending messages certainly are spam! I didn't ask for them to be sent, and you have to unsubscribe from _each_ site individually. They go straight to the trash folder

Comment: It's possible that enough SE users have been marking them as spam in Google that Google has blacklisted the domain.

Comment: @RobertHarvey more likely they've marked the *bounty* emails as spam, from the message it sounds like it's recognizing the content, and unless this is very recent my latest SE emails haven't gone to spam. Haven't got one of these for a bit though

Comment: @lunboks I always do :)

Comment: @BenBrocka: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: @yoda: [I agree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129212/1438).

Answer (score 4):

Google gives [a list of reasons](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=1366858&expand=5) this message *might* be spam.  The most likely seem to be:

> - Content that's usually associated with spam such as mature content and "get rich quick" schemes
> - Behavior of other Gmail users, such as many people reporting spam from a particular sender
> - Similarity to other spam or phishing messages based on a combination of things like subject matter, elements like spelling and formatting, and suspicious attachments

My money is on other Gmail users reporting [that particular message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129212/do-we-need-email-for-bounties-that-cant-be-awarded) type as spammy.

If you want to avoid having messages from Stack Exchange marked as spam, [Google](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9008) has some suggestions.

They also have [advice](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126) on increasing the odds of emails to Gmail users getting through.

Comment: It's a good policy, I much prefer my emails to have *immature* content ;)