# Nagging users to award a bounty when they can't

Tags: bug, bounties, notifications

I posted a bounty to a fairly corner-case question at [new-WindowsImage stalls with 0x8007007E, can't load unattend.dll](https://serverfault.com/questions/700839/new-windowsimage-stalls-with-0x8007007e-cant-load-unattend-dll) . Sadly, 30 minutes after posting the bounty, I realized what the answer was. That's fine though, I understand how bounties work.

There are still no other answers to the question, so nobody can get the bounty. But I still get system notifications and emails pleading with me to award the bounty before it expires.

These emails and notifications should only be sent if a bounty can actually be awarded.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129212/274942) (for email notifications).

Comment: Do you really think I gave SE my real email? This is not a dupe. *SE*, stop bugging me.