# Share this link box popping up of its own accord when I upvote a question

Tags: bug, popups, share-this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upvote = Permalink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101383/upvote-permalink)

Sometimes the Sharebox for 'Share this link' will pop up after I upvote a question, but I didn't click on the facebook or twitter icons.

This is a little annoying and I assume it is not supposed to happen.

Comment: I've noticed that the Share Link box pops up when opening a question. I just assumed I was clicking too much.

Comment: Really [the Facebook "post to profile"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/share-facebook.png), right? And not [the "share a link to this question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101383/upvote-permalink), which is by design.

Comment: @Arjan - thanks, it never bothered me enough to search, I just noticed this question today.

Comment: (Hehe, I was actually asking Tobe, but I now understand that @Dave surely saw the "Share a link" box.)

Comment: This is by Design!  I'm not sure I agree with the design.  If it went away when I clicked elsewhere It wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: Also if it is by design, it doesn't seem to happen every time.

Comment: @TobyAllen: read Jeff's answer in the linked question. It's _by design_ that it's random.